# Set menubar height to full page height

Tags: css

I have a problem with getting the height of my vertical menubar the same as the rest of the page.

So I have it like this

```
<div id="header">Site title etc</div>
<div id="pagecontent">
  <div id="menubar">Menu buttons<div>
  <div id="pageinnercontent">Contents of the page</div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
html {
  min-height:           100%;
}
body {
  min-height:               100%;
}
#pagecontent{
  position:         absolute;
  width:                100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#menubar{
  height:               100%;
  position:         absolute;
  width:                170px;
  background-color: #404040;
  color:                white;
  float:                left;
  bottom:           0;
}

#pageinnercontent{
    width:              calc(100% - 170px);
    left:               170px;
    position:           absolute;
}
```

However, it is not working. When the contents of pageinnercontent is "longer" than the menu, the menu is not made longer. Please help.

Comment: Works fine for me. Check the structure of your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flex and don't forget margin

Here is an example, it doesn't looks exactly well in stackoverflow context, but in standalone it's valid (with )

```css
html {
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  }
body {
 
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;

  }
.menu {
  min-width:300px;
  background-color:red;
  border:solid 3px black;
  min-height:100%;
  }
.main {
  background-color:yellow;
  border:solid 3px blue;
  min-height:100%;
  flex:1;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
     <div class="menu">
       Menu Is Here
       </div>
    <div class="main">
      Main Is Here
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For today - FLEX is the only modern layout CSS 3.0 facility to be used in Application-like layouting and for one-screen sites. Floats, grids and javascript on-resize hacks for now are old-school. Most browsers provides valid flex-*** support - Mozilla, Chrome, IE9(!), Opera - all for both PC and mobile versions.

About flexes U can see here (for start):  http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Just do Z-index of 2 for for the menu bar and 1 for content. That ensures that the menu bar will always be on top.

```css
html {
  height:           100%;
}
body {
  height:               100%;
}
#pagecontent{
  position:         absolute;
  width:                100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
#menubar{
  height:               100%;
  position:         absolute;
  width:                170px;
  background-color: #404040;
  color:                white;
  float:                left;
  top: 0;
  bottom:           0;
  z-index: 2;
}

#pageinnercontent{
    width:              calc(100% - 170px);
    left:               170px;
    position:           absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">Site title etc</div>
<div id="pagecontent">
  <div id="menubar">Menu buttons<div>
  <div id="pageinnercontent">Contents of the page</div>
</div>
```

**Note** With the current structure and CSS ensures that the menu stretches to the bottom and a higher z-index number that all other elements ensures that it is always seen.